# Plagiarism problem

Tags: ethics, probability, applied-philosophy

I have two exactly similar essays from my students. By the rules they should fail the class. But they claim that it's just coincidence. Taking into consideration the fact, that there is nonzero probability for two essays to be the same, is it correct to fail them?

Excuse me if this is not the right place to post this question.

Comment: This is probably going to be migrated to [Academia.SE](http://academia.stackexchange.com). But there is a philosophical question about the interplay between probability and ethics in here somewhere.

Comment: If asking as a matter of practice, then this is for academia.se. If asking as a question about morality, then you're going to have to tell us what conditions you're asking under.

Comment: The answer would depend critically on how similar.  "Exactly the same" is different than "makes essentially the same points in the same order".

Comment: 'Exactly Similar' is awesome.  I think this belongs on this site just so we can attempt to unravel the philosophical implications of that highly impressive phrase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 26 symbols in English. There would have been maybe 1000 symbols in an essay. So the probability of having two essays the same is 10^(-78). But if we consider the fact, that the text wasn't typed randomly there would be more chance of it. But believe me, there is more chance if we all die now than that two essays to be same without plagiarism.

Comment: The math is wrong, the analysis is wrong on the unhelpful side (English is _profoundly_ nonrandom, and an essay for a class is _profoundly_ constrained within valid English texts).  Also, there are very few instances where "believe me" makes a compelling argument in front of a philosophically sophisticated crowd.

Comment: I agree that the probability calculation is well off, for the reasons mentioned. Such a calculation, I guess, be impossible, since there's no easy way to demarcate which strings of words count as a plausible essay and which do not. Still, the claim that it would be more likely for us to all die now than for two essays to be identical seems probably right, regardless of the argumentative power of 'believe me' -- however you count it, it is going to be very *very* unlikely.

Comment: "But if we consider the fact, that the text wasn't typed randomly there would be more chance of it." I calculated the chance of to random texts to be the same.